# Remove entity with EF in many-to-many relation

Tags: entity-framework, many-to-many

I have a DbContext with three tables. There is many-to-many connection between Items and Orders.

```
public virtual DbSet<Item> Items { get; set; }
public virtual DbSet<Order> Orders { get; set; }
public virtual DbSet<ItemOrder> ItemOrders { get; set; }
```

also I have a method for removing a record from ItemOrders.

```
public void RemoveItemFromOrder(ItemOrder itemOrder) 
{     
    itemOrder.Item.Orders.Remove(itemOrder);    
    context.ItemOrders.Remove(itemOrder);   
    context.SaveChanges();  
}
```

(this code was written by previous developer). 
I need to understand, why can't I  just remove itemorder from ItemOrders in the context? Why do I need also to remove itemOrder from collection of (item)orders in connected item?

Comment: Explore a bit, what happens when you run that function without it ?

Comment: Everything seems to be OK. but this code was written by a very skillful person. i need to understand, why did he wrote it